# The modal doesn't appear

Tags: 8, ajax

I want to output a link in a modal window, using the *Simple Link* approach shown on [Make Mine a Modal](https://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-4/issue-1/make-mine-modal).

When the link is clicked, the little animated spinner appears, and I can see the response returned via AJAX using the browser inspector. Still, no modal appears and there aren't errors reported in the console.

Do I need to add some markup to the theme I am using, which will be used as modal container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The markup I was using contained the wrong CSS attribute: Instead of `data-accepts`, it should use `data-dialog-type`, as in the following example.

```html
    <a href="/blah" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{"width":500}">Show me a 500px wide modal</a>
```

I was using the wrong attribute after reading some outdated articles. Once I found the following comment on [Understanding Drupal 8's Modal API and Dialog Controller](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/understanding-drupal-8s-modal-api-and-dialog-controller), I understood what my error was.

> The dialog API changed since the blog post was created. Maybe you'll update your samples based on my example.
>
> ```php
> // Build link for dialog.
> $link_url = Url::fromRoute('entity.taxonomy_term.add_form', ['taxonomy_vocabulary' => 'vocab_name']);
> $link_url->setOptions([
>   'attributes' => [
>     'class' => ['use-ajax'],
>     'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
>     'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode(['width' => 700]),
> ]));
> $link_add_unit_display_name = \Drupal::l('Create unit display name', $link_url);
>
> Regards,
> SteffenR
> ```